# Integrating a line tangent to the unit circle

Tags: calculus, integration

We all know the derivative of the unit circle is $-\frac{x}{y}$. When I apply this derivative to $60^\circ$ $(1/2, \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}})$, you get the equation: $y=-1/3*\sqrt{3}x+1/3(2*\sqrt{3})$ which is all great and fine, until it is integrated, which gives us a completely different result than the original $x^2+y^2=1$. So why is that?

Comment: Updated question for clarity

Comment: The differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$ has (among others) the top half of the unit circle and the bottom half as solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by 'differentiating the unit circle' you mean differentiating the equation

$$x^2+y^2=1$$ with respect to the independent variable $x$.

If we do so, we get (by implicit differentiation)

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{y},$$

a formula for the derivative which depends on both $x$ and $y$.

When you say 'apply the derivative to 60 degrees', it means 'find the slope of the line tangent to the circle at the point $(1/2, \sqrt {3/2})$.

Then the equation of the tangent line is

$$y=-\frac{\sqrt3}{3}x+\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}. $$

Now you shouldn't expect to get the equation of the circle by integrating the equation of the tangent line. The tangent line is NOT the derivative of the circle; it is just a line tangent to the circle.

If you really want to recover the equation of the circle from the derivative, you should solve the differential equation

$$xdx=-ydy.$$

This is a separable equation, so integrating with respect to the corresponding variables yields

$$\frac{x^2}{2}=-\frac{y^2}{2}+C$$ for some constant $C$.

Since the point $(0,1)$ is on the circle, we get $C=1/2$.

And so finally, we get back

$$x^2+y^2=1.$$

Comment: @ZacheryUtt Welcome to MSE! Don't forget to upvote and accept answers if your question has been answered properly.

Comment: Even "differentiating the equation" seems to abuse terminology a bit.